# wp + slider + url + jquery blur

Tags: php, jquery

I have a wp site. a slider with caption + url.
i want to get on each slide a button with "Read more" and the url from the slider (input in admin panel).

i have the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var imgLink = $("#flex-container-43 ul li a").blur(function() {$("#flex-container-43 ul li a").attr("href")});
console.log(imgLink);
$('#flex-container-43').prepend('<a href="' + imgLink + '"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/button.png" class="buttonimg" /></a>');
});
</script>
```

and I get the blog url followed by `/[object Object]`

any idea/hand on this?
thanks in advance for the time you guys! 
cheers!

Comment: When your question has been answered, please mark the correct answer as _accepted_. This is not a 90s message board so we don't do this by editing "solved" into the title. You've been here for over a year and already accepted answers to several other questions so I feel like you should know this by now. :)

Comment: my bad, sorry on that. cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the imgLink variable to an element (or more correctly a jQuery object which represents the elements and its associated methods).

Change:

```
var imgLink = $("#flex-container-43 ul li a").blur(function() {$("#flex-container-43 ul li a").attr("href")});
```

To:

```
var imgLink = "";
$("#flex-container-43 ul li a").blur(function() {
   imgLink = $("#flex-container-43 ul li a").attr("href")
});
```

This will create a variable for imgLink within the required scope, then place the `href` attribute into that variable when the event fires.

P.S: Your code may still not do what you want, i have only answered why you get the object returning and not the href attribute. The code in its current format doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: hi Lee! thanks a lot for the answer and explaining. changed that and am getting an empty string now in console.log

Comment: solved! 

used .prepend img to the link. thanks a lot for the support!